# Join of data from one column into one string

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

in postgreSQL database I have table with Name(string) column.

```
ID| Name
1 | a
2 | b
3 | c
4 | d
```

With one query I would like to retrieve all names from the table into one string in the format:

```
'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string_agg()`:

```
select string_agg(distinct '''' || name || '''', ', ' order by id)
from t;
```

For most purposes, though, I would suggest using arrays instead:

```
select array_agg(name order by id)
from t
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that the data has to be unique.

Comment: `select string_agg('''' || subquery.name || '''', ', ' order by id)
from (select distinct name from table) as subquery` WORKS

Comment: @panmigal: I'd rather use the simple `select string_agg(distinct ...)`.